# Get a Value from a JsonArray and store it in array

Tags: java, arrays, json

I am trying to extract "score from the following set of ArrayofJson

I just want, score 1,2,1,3 store in an array. like int sample[] = {1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1};
how can we do it?

```
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public static void main(String args[]) { 
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(
"[{\"Qnum\":1124,\"Response\":\"London\\n\",\"SelectedResponse\":\"1\",\"Score\":1.0},{\"Qnum\":1125,\"Response\":\"Sydney\\n\",\"SelectedResponse\":\"2\",\"Score\":2.0},{\"Qnum\":1126,\"Response\":\"Paris\\n\",\"SelectedResponse\":\"1\",\"Score\":1.0},{\"Qnum\":1183,\"Response\":\"NewYork\\n\",\"SelectedResponse\":\"3\",\"Score\":3.0}]");
      for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
          JSONObject json = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
          Iterator<String> keys = json.keys();
         System.out.println(json.getDouble("Score"));
}
```

Comment: If you only want the `Score` field, why are you iterating over all the fields of the JSON object? Just call [`json.getDouble("Score")`](https://stleary.github.io/JSON-java/org/json/JSONObject.html#getDouble-java.lang.String-)

Comment: Why did you say "gson" in the title and tag it with `gson`, when your code is using class `org.json.JSONObject`? The Gson class is named `com.google.gson.JsonObject`.

Answer (score 0):

1. JSON Array looks like this [1,2,3,4], not {1,2,3,4}

This can help you.

```
    // If You Wanted to have JSONArray
    
    List<Double> scores = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject json = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
        double score = json.getDouble("Score");
        scores.add(score);
    }

    JSONArray array = new JSONArray(scores);
    System.out.println(array);

    // If You Wanted to have Java Array of double
    double []scoresDouble = new double[jsonArray.length()];

    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject json = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
        double score = json.getDouble("Score");
        scoresDouble[i] = score;
    }

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(scoresDouble));

    // If You Wanted to have Java Array of int (as mentioned on the questing)
    int []scoresInt = new int[jsonArray.length()];

    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject json = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
        double score = json.getDouble("Score");
        scoresInt[i] = (int) score;
    }

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(scoresInt));
```